# How to access class properties of Jest Test Environment inside child test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have created a testing environment for jest. It's based very closely to [their official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).

I am setting a few values in the constructor that I would like to make available to the tests that are used within the environment. (See `this.foo = bar`).

#### Testing Env:

```
// my-custom-environment
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
    this.testPath = context.testPath;
    this.foo = 'bar'; // Trying to access
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    await someSetupTasks(this.testPath);
    this.global.someGlobalObject = createGlobalObject();
  }

  async teardown() {
    this.global.someGlobalObject = destroyGlobalObject();
    await someTeardownTasks();
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

I run my tests using the equivalent of:

```
jest --env ./tests/<testing-env>.js
```

Where do I access `this.foo` within my tests that are tested within this testing environment?

```
describe('Sample Test', () => {
  it('this.foo = bar', () => {
    expect(this.foo).toBe('bar');
  });
});
```

I tried replacing both arrow functions with es5 function formats (hoping that `this` would be in scope) and didn't have any luck.

How can I get class properties from my testing environment from within my tests in that environment?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. You'd have to expose it in your setup func as `this.global.foo = 'bar'` then you can access it in your test suite by just calling `foo`.

Comment: Not what I was *hoping* to hear, but I have tested and confirmed this is a viable solution. If you would like to write this as an answer I'd be glad to mark it as accepted. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Anytime! Let me know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. I'd recommend exposing `foo` in a similar manner as  `this.global.someGlobalObject = createGlobalObject();` and add `this.global.foo = 'bar'` within the `setup` function. You can then access this variable within your test suites by calling `foo`.

```
// my-custom-environment
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
    this.testPath = context.testPath;
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    await someSetupTasks(this.testPath);
    this.global.someGlobalObject = createGlobalObject();
    this.global.foo = 'bar'; // <-- will make foo global in your tests
  }

  async teardown() {
    this.global.someGlobalObject = destroyGlobalObject();
    await someTeardownTasks();
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

Then within your test suite:

```
// test suite
describe('Sample Test', () => {
  it('foo = bar', () => {
    expect(foo).toBe('bar'); // <-- foo since it's globally accessible 
  });
});
```

Comment: Definitely not ideal but I appreciate the method!

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is add a set function to your constructor.

```
setThis(key, val) {
   if (process.env.TEST) this[key] = val
}
```

And perhaps build the same for a `getThis()`